# Getting error while launching new Activity for Updating the database of recyclerview

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to transfer some details in the next activity but getting the error when I'm launching the new Intent 
Error:

> Caused by android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
>           at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:468)
>           at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
>           at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
>           at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
>           at com.shashankesh.ms.ItemIncrsDecrs.onCreate(ItemIncrsDecrs.java:42)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7032)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1236)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)

The parent Activity from which I'm launching is:

```
@Override
public void onClick(int Id) {
    Toast.makeText(this,String.format("ID: "+Id),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent startInt = new Intent(ItemActivity.this,ItemIncrsDecrs.class);
    startInt.putExtra("ID",Id);
    startActivity(startInt);

}
```

This is the Activity I'm launching

```
public class ItemIncrsDecrs extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private int mId;
private String mItemName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_incrs_decrs);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.incrs_decrs_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    // Create a DB helper (this will create the DB if run for the first time)
    ItemDbHelper dbHelper = new ItemDbHelper(this);
    // Keep a reference to the mDb until paused or killed. Get a writable database
    // because you will be adding restaurant customers
    Intent intentThatStartedThisActivity = getIntent();

    if (intentThatStartedThisActivity != null) {
        if (intentThatStartedThisActivity.hasExtra("ID")) {
            mId = intentThatStartedThisActivity.getIntExtra("ID",0);
        }
    }
    mDb = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = queryItemName();
    mItemName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME));
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Update Item: " + mItemName);
    //updateItem();
}

private Cursor queryItemName() {
    String[] columns = {ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME};
    String selection = ItemContract.ItemEntry._ID + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(mId)};
    String groupBy = null;
    String having = null;
    String orderBy = ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP;
    return getContentResolver().query(
            ItemContract.ItemEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP
    );
}
```

I'm launching the above activity to implement updating the item's value in the new activity, and returning to parent activity after it.

And for the Content provider, I'm using this code

```
@Override
public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    // Get access to underlying database (read-only for query)
    final SQLiteDatabase db = mItemDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    // Write URI match code and set a variable to return a Cursor
    int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    Cursor retCursor;

    //  Query for the tasks directory and write a default case
    switch (match) {
        // Query for the tasks directory
        case TASKS:
            retCursor =  db.query(TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder);
            break;
        // Default exception
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
    }

    //  Set a notification URI on the Cursor and return that Cursor
    retCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

    // Return the desired Cursor
    return retCursor;
}
```

Please help me to resolve the above error

Answer (score 1):

you need to call cursor.movetofirst() before retrieving any data from it. So call it before your line `mItemName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemContract.ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME));`